# Creating an array with large initial size in powershell

Tags: powershell

The only way I know to create an array in powershell is

`$arr = @(1, 2, 3)`

However, this creating method is not convenient if I want to create an array with large initial size such as 10000.

Because I don't want to write code like this

`$arr = @(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ... ,0) # 10000 0s in this line of code`

Writing code like the following is not efficient.

```
$arr = @()
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10000; $i++) {
  $arr += 0
}
```

Because whenever `+=` operator is executed, all of the elements in the old array would be copied into a newly created array.

What's the best way to create an array with large initial size in powershell?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use `New-Object` in this case:

```sh
PS> $arr = New-Object int[] 10000; $arr.length
10000
```

Or, in PSv5+, using the static `new()` method on the type:

```sh
PS> $arr = [int[]]::new(10000); $arr.length
10000
```

These commands create a **strongly typed array**, using base type `[int]` in this example.
If the use case allows it, this is preferable for reasons of performance and type safety.

If you need to **create an "untyped" array** the same way that PowerShell does (`[System.Object[]]`), substitute `object` for `int`; e.g., `[object[]]::new(10000)`; the elements of such an array will default to `$null`.
[TessellatingHeckler's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083644/45375), however, shows a much **more concise** alternative that even allows you **initialize all elements to a specific value**.

---

Arrays have a fixed size; if you **need an array-like data structure that you can preallocate *and* grow dynamically**, see [Bluecakes' helpful `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`-based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083117/45375).

[`[System.Collections.ArrayList]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) is the resizable analog to `[System.Object[]]`, and its ***generic* equivalent** - which like the `[int[]]` example above - allows you to **use a *specific* type** for performance and robustness (if feasible), is **[`[System.Collections.Generic.List[<type>]]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)**, e.g.:

```sh
PS> $lst = [System.Collections.Generic.List[int]]::New(10000); $lst.Capacity
10000
```

Note that - as with `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` - specifying an *initial capacity* (`10000`, here) does not allocate the internally used array with that size *right away* - the capacity value is simply stored (and exposed as property `.Capacity`), and an internal array with that capacity (internal size that leaves room for growth) is allocated *on demand*, when the first element is added to the list.

`[System.Collections.Generic.List[<type>]]`'s `.Add()` method commendably does *not* produce output, whereas `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`'s does (it returns the index of the element that was just added).

```sh
# The non-generic ArrayList's .Add() produces (usually undesired) output.
PS> $al = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new(); $al.Add('first elem')
0  # .Add() outputs the index of the newly added item

# Simplest way to suppress this output:
PS> $null = $al.Add('first elem')
# NO output.

# The generic List[T]'s .Add() does NOT produce output.
PS> $gl = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new(); $gl.Add('first elem')
# NO output from .Add()
```

Answer (score 13):

Array literal multiplication:

```
$arr = @($null) * 10000
```

Comment: Nicely done. For creating a regular PowerShell array (`[System.Object[]]`) this is by far the simplest solution, and it allows initialization with specific values too.
(With really big arrays, this initialization comes at a cost, but that will probably rarely matter).
To make it specific to the OP's example: `$arr = , 0 * 10000`.

Comment: It's a total quibble, but perhaps interesting: `@($null)` is an application of the array-subexpression operator, not an _array literal_.
Even `, $null` isn't an array literal - it's an application of `,`, the array-construction operator.
To quote from [PowerShell in Action, 2nd Edition](https://www.amazon.com/Windows-PowerShell-Action-Second-Payette/dp/1935182137): "Here’s how array literals are defined in PowerShell: 
_They’re not. There’s no array literal notation in PowerShell._ […]  instead of having array literals, there’s a set of operations that create collections as needed. "

Comment: @mklement0 it is interesting, and I see comma parsed as 'an operator', but I wonder what meaningful distinction it makes compared to it being "a literal"? Is it something related to it being dynamic / evaluated closer to runtime, e.g. related to being able to do `$a, $b` ?  `"foo"` is a string literal, presumably, but does that imply `"$foo"` is not?

Comment: I guess all it means is that there's no _separate, dedicated syntax_ (such as C#'s `{ …, …, … }`) for _initializing_ arrays in PS - just operators that help you construct arrays on demand.
It's not related to whether the array _elements_ are literals or not.

Answer (score 6):

In `PowerShell` you are correct in that `+=` will destroy the old array and create a new array with the new items.

For working with a large collection of items i would highly recommend using the `ArrayList` type from .NET as this is not a fixed size array so `PowerShell` will not destroy it every time you add an item to it and i've found this to work better in my projects.

Using `ArrayList` also means that you don't need to start with 10000 items. Because `PowerShell` won't need to recreate your array every time, you can start with 0 and then add each item as it's needed instead of starting with 10000.

So in your script i would create an empty `ArrayList` like so

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$arr = @()
```

and then when you need to add something to it just call `.Add()` (You don't need to prepopulate the array with 10000 items, it will expand as you add items).

```
$arr.Add([int]0)
```

Your example using an `ArrayList`:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$arr = @()
for ($i = 1; $i -le 10000; $i++) {
    $arr.Add([int]0)
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. Can I suggest you also show how to specify an initial capacity?
Also, it's worth pointing out that the `.Add()` method produces output (the index at which the element was added), which may be unexpected, `$null = $arr.Add([int] 0)` is one way to suppress that output.

Answer (score 1):

You could always do this:

```
$a = @(0..9999)
$a.length
```

This is nearly like what you are already doing, except that you don't have to
write out all the values.

Comment: The `@(...)` around the range-operator expression essentially creates the array _twice_, which is undesirable; simply use `$a = 0...9999`. That said, it seems that the OP wants to initialize all array elements to `0`.